# Use of find in unix on strange file/directory names

Tags: unix, csh, tcsh

Im a beginner scripter, writing scripts in tcsh and csh(these are teached in my course)

Im writing a script which uses find for putting path of directories 
this is the part of the script:

```
set list = (`find $cesta -type d`)
```

it works fine until the file or directory names arent named such as:
fi@@lename&& or −filename or :−,?!drectoryanem!-``

These special characters i couldnt handle i changed the find script to:

```
set list = ("`find $cesta -type d`")
```

bit none of these works, when i want to use the path from the list in this next script:

```
foreach i ($list:q)
   foreach file (`find "$i" -maxdepth 1 -type f`)
   ....
   end
end
```

it couldnt handle these special file names, so i get many errors like find: −."!filenda no such filename or directory